# Networking failing on both wired and wireless connections

Tags: networking, network-manager

Running 11.10 on a Lenovo B570, maybe a month old. When I try to connect to a network, wired or wireless, `nm-applet` does its normal "connecting" animation, but sort of "spasming" at the end of the loop. I think what appears in that icon's place for a frame or so might be a "loading applet" icon. After maybe a minute, the applet gives up trying to connect. This behavior started in the past several hours and has persisted after a reboot.

This output may be relevant:

```
$ netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
```

**7 March 2012**

This has now [resurfaced](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111037/networking-failing-on-both-wired-and-wireless-connections-again). In hopes of providing further useful information:

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!